# Grimmett and Stirzaker Exercise 3.8.5 p71

Tags: probability

Pepy's problem: Sam rolls $6n$ dice once; he needs at least $n$ sixes. Issac rolls $6(n+1)$ dice and needs at least $n+1$ sixes.

Who is more likely to get the number of sixes they need?

Their proof proceed's as follows:

$\begin{align} P(X_{n+1} \geq n+1 &= \sum_{r=0}^6 P(X_n \geq n+ 1 - r)P(Y=r) \\
&=P(X_n \geq n) + \sum_{r=0}^6 [P(X_n \geq n+ 1 - r)-P(X_n \geq n)]P(Y=r)
\end{align}$

They then set $g(k)=P(X_n=k)$ and use the fact that $g(n) \geq g(n-1) \geq ... \geq(n-5)$ to find the last sum is no bigger than

$g(n)\sum_{r=0}^6(r-1)P(Y=r)=g(n)(E(Y)-1)$

They then say the claim follows because $E(Y)=1$.

I'm confused by two parts:

1.) Why is $g(n) \geq g(n-1)$ surely this is contrary to Newton's solution to Pepy's problem, where the smaller the n the higher the probability?

2.) If the last summation is zero then this would suggest that $P(X_{n+1} \geq n+1) = P(X_n \geq n)$ again violating Newton's solution?

Comment: Your problem statement must have a few typos.  Can you edit?  It could make quite a big difference in the interpretation of the problem.  For instance, Sam rolls "two $6n$ dice once"?  What does that mean, exactly?  Is the "two" supposed to be there?